# Microsoft Word 2010 Add-in Unknown Publisher

Tags: ms-word, add-in, word-2010

When I am Installing My Customized Word Add-in on Client Machine it is Giving this Warning "Unknow Publisher Install or Dont Install".

How do get I get rid of this warning?

Comment: You need to sign it:  Check Microsoft's [Click Once security](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/t71a733d.aspx) page

Comment: Thanx For Reply But i Already Created Temporary (.pfx) and After Creating the Installer and Installing on Client machine It is Showing this Warning .How get Rid of it.I Have Pic also But,Bcz of Some issue I am Not Able to Post .Please Help..

Answer (score 0):

The certificate you create (a temporary one) is only valid for your computer.

To get rid of "unknown publisher" you need to sign you addin with a code signing certificate purchased from a trusted authority. To buy one you'll need to contact that authority, and prove your identity.

Some list of code signing authorities can be found in this topic for example:
https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1077800/which-code-signing-authority-should-i-go-with